# How to import a XML file to 'Charles Proxy > Map Local' through command line

Tags: debugging, charles-proxy

I want to use different Map Local Configuration settings in my automation. I need a command to import XML to Mal Local in charles proxy tool.

Any idea how to import a XML file to 'Charles Proxy > Map Local' through command line

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Charles in command line mode, but it seems your only option is to start charles using the `-config` flag, which lets you start it with different configurations ([see documentation here](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/command-line-options/))

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: Certainly not. It seems to be quite a corner case so probably no one will be able to give a detailed answer, except from @dhananjay-hanchate (if he finally achieved it!).

Answer (score 0):

You can't import a previously exported "Map Local" xml file into Charles from the command line, but as stated, you *can* import a config file.

What's left out of the above answer is how to get the config file and how to make sure it contains the Map Local data.

To do that, first, open Charles in regular GUI mode (not command line), and import the Map using Map Local -> import

[image]

Once you do that, your Map Local settings will be automatically saved to the Charles default config file.  The Charles config is located at different places depending on OS, all listed here:

https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/deploying-license-keys-during-installation/

You can copy this config file to another location on your machine.  When you want to load the file, start Charles using the -config option as outlined above, and give it the path of your saved config with your Map Local data saved.